# Can I open an IRA as a US citizen living outside the country?

Tags: united-states, ira

My husband and I each had an IRA while living and working in Boston. We moved to to Ireland in 2001. Merrill Lynch has resigned from our account recently and the reason given was due to us not residing in the USA. Are we still entitled to have an account and if so do you know what companies will do so?

Answer (score 2):

There is no prohibition regarding having an IRA while living outside of the USA.

Banks are lazy and simply don't want to deal with the additional compliance of administering your funds. More bluntly, the amounts in your accounts aren't worth it to Merrill Lynch.

Transfer your IRA and accounts to a different institution. Although, if you lack a US address, you might find opening and maintaining accounts to be a recurring problem with US banks. But again, they'll override internal policy and ignore banking industry regulation if the amounts you want to deposit are non-negligible.